# How to use a USB Switch effectively? Data Transfer etc

Tags: hard-drive, usb, speed, data-transfer

This is my first time posting here, so feel free to correct me if I do something wrong.

I am currently trying to optimize my workflow during the time of home office etc. I had the idea to use a usb switch (or maybe multiple) to optimize switching from working on my laptop to my pc.

Ideally it works like this: The headset, webcam, mousey keyboard and maybe a harddrive are connected to the usb switch. A button click changes whether the input is send to the pc or the laptop.

From what I have researched there are usb switches that kind of fulfill what im looking for. But since I want to play video games and also have a harddrive connected I am worried that the transfer speed will be significantly slower. It seems like usb hubs will "divide" the bandwith given by a usb port and a lot of usb switches work with usb hubs internally.

My question is, will the usb switch slow down data transfer if the switch is implemented without a usb hub?

Thanks in advance. I hope the question is described well enough.

Answer (score 0):

A USB switch can only work with an internal hub, so bandwidth is always going to be an issue. For optimal results you will want to work with USB3 and if you have just one USB drive connected to that switch with a mouse and keyboard attached, you likely won't notice much of a slowdown. A headset and camera will get you into slower stuff if you use these devices at the same time.

This means, you copy large files, while listening on the headset and using the camera and try to type at the same time, then you will indeed notice lag on all devices. But if you copy files and not use the headset and camera, you are likely going to not notice it, or it is so marginal that its not that big of an issue.

Comment: Alright I didnt know that a switch always has a usb hub integrated. Thanks for the fast answer, I think I´ll just give it a try then wit only mouse and keyboard and add things onto that.